# Fetch one record from relationship for Datatable

Tags: laravel, datatable, relationship, laravel-8, eager-loading

I'm using *Laravel v8*

I have 3 models as:**Family, FamilyMember, FamilyRelationship**

> Family table:

| id | address | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | NULL | NULL |

> Family Relationship table:

| id | name | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Head | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | Spouse | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | Child | NULL | NULL |

> Family Member table:

| id | first_name | last_name | family_id | family_relationship_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Jane | Doe | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | Max | Doe | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | Mary | Doe | 1 | 3 |

I have created relation in the Family model as

```
public function members(){
   return $this->hasMany(FamilyMember::class, 'family_id');
}
```

And Family Relationship relation in Family Member model as

```
public function familyrelationship()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(FamilyRelationship::class, 'family_relationship_id');
}
```

I'm using Datatable to display the Family Information along with *Head of the family*

I want to display columns **id** and **address** from *Family* model and **first_name** and **last_name** from *Family Member* model where the family member relationship is **Head**.

How should go ahead with making relationship to display only head of the family detail in the datatable grid which is searchable too?

Above thing can be easily achieved using eloquent JOINs but I want to know if this can be achieved using relationship functionality provided by Laravel.

Comment: what had you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try whereHas mixing with hasOne , to build a new relation:

```
public function members(){
   return $this->hasMany(FamilyMember::class, 'family_id');
}
```

// then your new relation:

```
public function head(){
        return $this->hasOne(FamilyMember::class, 'family_id')->whereHas('familyrelationship',function ($query){
            $query->where('name','Head');
        });
    }
```

`hasOne`, will take only first result ...